# Show preview of a view inside another view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7

I have a `UIView`, let me say `previewBackgroundView` of frame `(60, 154, 200, 200)`. It is a subview to `self.view`.

Then I have a dynamic view, say `dynamicView` of frame `(0, 0, 260, 100)`. It may contain any number of subcomponents in it, like `UIButton`, `UILabel`, etc.

**Note**: The `dynamicView` can be of any size. I am passing `dynamicView` as an argument in the method.

When I add the `dynamicView` as subview to the `previewBackgroundView`, it goes out of `previewBackgroundView`'s bounds. So, I'd like to adjust the size of the `dynamicView` and its children so that its position is center to the `previewBackgroundView` and `dynamicView` is inside `previewBackgroundView`'s bounds. Simply to say, I have to show the `dynamicView` like a preview in `previewBackgroundView` - no matter how big `dynamicView` is.

My first attempt was setting `clipsToBounds`, its not working in Xcode5, iOS7. I welcome your ideas on the alternate options.

Comment: take dynamicView to `UIScrollview`.

Comment: Use autolayout or the spring and struts to make the view and its subviews flexible, then just change the size the view view, it will constrain the view according to the layout constraints you specified.

Comment: `UIScrollView`? I do not want to zoom in/out the `dynamicView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If your dynamic view is bigger than your previewBackgroundView than you should resize the dynamicView maintaining the aspect ratio. Scale down in such a way that it comes inside the preview BackgroundView.

You can use the scale property for the same like below:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1, 1);
```

Or

2) You may keep the dynamic view with the size view want and make the content in the dynamic view scrollable using a scrollview.

I suggest you to choose the 2nd option.

Comment: Man. You resolved my two days headache in a single line of code.